# Receive service bus queue messages in a web role

Tags: azure

All the examples I find about Service Bus Queues are in the scenario where the web role sends the message and there's a dedicated worker role receiving the messages.

Mi situation is different. The worker role is the one that generates the messages and must be received by the web role.

I guess that the RoleEntryPoint of the webrole should have an infinite while that listens for new messages, but the messages received must be processed by components in my webrole and as far as I know the RoleEntryPoint is not accesible from the web app.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's absolutely no difference whether you send or receive the message from a web role or worker role, as they're both Windows Server 2012 VM instances. You can spin up threads from the `Run()` method, or from wherever else you want. You could even write a separate console app to process service bus messages, or even receive them from an app running on your own desktop.

Just treat Service Bus as a *service* that's consumable from your apps, wherever they may be (and in whatever language you're working with).

Comment: Thanks David, your answer is very clear. How can I implement it in a web role? It is advisable to start a separate thread in the global.asax to listen to the queue? I cannot use the RoleEntryPoint because it runs in a different process.

Comment: Hey David, with this being said would you recommend starting (`Task.Run()`) an infinite loop inside of a Web Role or using the `onMessage()`?